# UIPageView Default page

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I created a simple app 
after click button I post page number to second view
This is  sample code

```
ChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
```

Startup page number is 0 but I want to start page what I post

```
ChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.pagenumber]];
```

But now work can some one help me please

Thank you

Comment: viewControllerAtIndex wants parameter to be integer but you are passing string instance - [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.pagenumber]

Comment: [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.pagenumber]; should do it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:[self.pagenumber intValue]];
```